# How to find elements that are not deeper than a selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, formcollection

I am building a jQuery plugin to manage form collections. The plugin aims to add <kbd>add</kbd>, <kbd>remove</kbd>, <kbd>move up</kbd> and <kbd>move down</kbd> buttons to alter that collection.

- A collection's root node always contains a selector, such as `.collection`.
- A button can be anything as soon as it has the `.add` class

I implemented `min` and `max` options, so <kbd>add</kbd> and <kbd>remove</kbd> buttons disappear accordingly. My problem comes up when I try to manage a collection of form collections: how to select only the <kbd>add</kbd> buttons that refers to the right collection?

To simplify the problem, look at the following HTML code:

```
<div class="collection">
  <div>something</div>
  <div>something</div>
  <div>
    <div class="add">+</div>
  </div>
  <div>something</div>
  <div class="collection">
    <div>something</div>
    <div>something</div>
    <div>
      <div class="add">+</div>
    </div>
    <div>something</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the button can be arbitrary deep: collection is built by an user and I don't know where can be the button in the dom. BTW, it is deeper than the `.collection`, that's all I know.

How to select all <kbd>add</kbd> buttons **until** the second `.collection`, but not further?

For those interested, this plugin is available (but in active dev) [here](https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony2-collection).

Comment: Select all `.add`, select all `.collection .collection .collection .add`, remove intersection

Comment: "How to select all add buttons **until** the second .collection, but not further?" At `html` , would that be _one_ `.add` element ?

Comment: @PaulS. there can be an arbitrary number of collections that encapsulate collections (even if that would be very strange to create collection of collections of collections iMHO).

Comment: @guest271314, this is useful sometimes to put 2 add buttons (one at the left and one at the right side for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume you have a reference to the `.collection` object that you want to find the `add` buttons for in a variable called `target`.  If so, you can do it like this:

```
target.find(".add").filter(function(i, element) {
   return $(element).closest(".collection").get(0) === target.get(0);
});
```

This finds all the `.add` buttons that are in a given `.collection` and then removes any who are contained in a nested `.collection` instead of directly in the target `.collection`.

Comment: I did not noticed that `.closest()` were using ancestors only. Very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @AlainTiemblo - I made a change to the code because I think it has to compare DOM elements, not jQuery objects.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(".add").not($(".collection:gt(0) .add"));
```

---

Note,

Utilizing jQuery [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)'s `.not( selector )` , where `selector` is selctor string

> **[.not( selector )](http://api.jquery.com/not/#not-selector)                              version added: 1.0**
>
> selector Type: Selector or Element or Array A string containing a
>   selector expression, a DOM element, or an array of elements to match
>   against the set.

`$(".add").not(".collection:gt(0) .add")` http://jsfiddle.net/47wc5L96/21/

did *not* appear to return same results as `.not( selection )` , where `selection` is jQuery object

> **[.not( selection )](http://api.jquery.com/not/#not-selection) version added: 1.4**
>
> selection Type: jQuery An
>   existing jQuery object to match the current set of elements against.

`$(".add").not($(".collection:gt(0) .add"));` http://jsfiddle.net/47wc5L96/20/

---

```js
console.log($(".add").not($(".collection:gt(0) .add")));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="collection">
  <div>something</div>
  <div>something</div>
  <div>
<div class="add">+</div>
  </div>
  <div>something</div>
  <div class="collection">
<div>something</div>
<div>something</div>
<div>
  <div class="add">+</div>
</div>
<div>something</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, looks working great for the top collection, but if I try to get add buttons from the 2nd one like this: http://jsfiddle.net/47wc5L96/25/ --- Sorry :p

Comment: @AlainTiemblo The top collection is perhaps interesting one to filter , as it contains nested collections having same class ; requiring removal of non-selected elements having parent container class. Nested , inner collections could be selected relatively directly http://jsfiddle.net/47wc5L96/26/

Comment: I know but that's not true, because I do not know how many nested collections I can have. Imagine I have a form that describe a REST response, letting user to choose between 3 fields: key, value and node, with a node that can contain an arbitrary number of nested key/value/node. We can imagine that the response will get deeper than 2 elements. BTW, don't worry, this is too complex to do that in jQuery (spent my day on it), I finally opted for distinct button's class prefixes for each collection. Thanks for ur time!